# How to display line number where an exception happens during runtime without a debugger?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have an exception happening during runtime which is non reproducible and therefore I can't debug it in the IDE/debugger. I want to know where in the code this happens so I surrounded the code with try/except statement, inserted a 'raise exception' statement for testing & displayed the stacktrace like this to see if it works:

```
   on e: exception do begin
          showmessage(e.StackTrace);
    end;
```

However the message displayed was empty. Why was it empty? Is there another way to know where an exception happened? Using Delphi XE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Exception.StackTrace](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.SysUtils.Exception.StackTrace) documentation indicates that the default implementation returns an empty string, and that in order to use the functionality you need to provide a [GetStackInfoStringProc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.SysUtils.Exception.GetStackInfoStringProc) procedure. It also suggests some implementations (both free and commercial) from third-party providers that can be used instead of writing your own.

Here's a (brief) excerpt from that documentation - visit the documentation page for the related links:

> By default, StackTrace is always an empty string. If you want StackTrace to contain an actual value, you must assign GetStackInfoStringProc a procedure that can generate a string from the stack information.
>
> **Using Exception.StackTrace**
>
> In order to use the StackTrace property to obtain the stack trace for exceptions, you have to use (or implement) a stack trace provider. There are a number of third-party solutions, both commercial and free.
>
> Some of the stack trace providers are:
>
> - [JEDI Code Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/) (the JclDebug and the JCLHookExcept unit).
> - [EurekaLog](https://www.eurekalog.com/)
> - [madExcept](http://www.madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm)
>
> For more information on how to use some of the above third-party stack trace providers, see the following blog posts:
>
> - [Working with Delphi’s new Exception.StackTrace](https://blog.gurock.com/working-with-delphis-new-exception-stacktrace/) (Tobias Gurock, 2009).
> - [CodeVerge - How to use Exception.StackTrace](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.general/how-to-use-exception.stacktrace/1041497) (2008).

Answer (score 4):

> However the message displayed was empty. Why was it empty?

Like Ken said, the `StackTrace` property is not implemented by default, per its documentation.  You have to install a 3rd party exception logger with stack trace capabilities to hook up the `StackTrace` property.

> Is there another way to know where an exception happened?

Without a viable stack trace, you would have to obtain the memory address of the code instruction where the exception actually occurred and then compare it to the list of addresses stored in the generated `.map` file for your compiled executable (if enabled in the Project Options, which is also necessary for stack tracing). With that, you can deduce which function the crashing code belongs to, but not necessarily the exact line of code.

If the exception is an [`EExternal`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.EExternal)-derived exception (like `EAccessViolation`), you can get the memory address from the `EExternal.ExceptionRecord` field (Windows only), or the `EExternal.ExceptionAddress` field (*Nix/OSX/iOS).  Otherwise, use the [`System.ExceptAddr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ExceptAddr) function.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use [synopse](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki/Synopse+OpenSource) framework, take a look at `TSQLLog` class in the documentation.

You only have to generate map file (converting to `.mab` by the framework) and distribute it with your application.

Add this uses in your project file: `Syncommons`, `momrmot` and `synlog`.

```
uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  SynCommons,
  mORMot,
  SynLog,
  F_calc in 'F_calc.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  TSQLLog.Family.Level := LOG_STACKTRACE; // LOG_VERBOSE


  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

A log file will be generate.
You can read it with this sample program (in the framework):

```
Synopse\SQLite3\Samples\11 - Exception logging\logview.dpr
```